# use file_get_contents to get image from url but get error :failed to open stream

Tags: php

I want to get the image and resize it then save, but when i use the url to get the image  and get the info of the image, error pop up.

```php
$content = file_get_contents('http://localhost//uploadImage/tipsImages/9a861a512bed4530456620c159e80220e9eaba7f.png');
            if (($img_info = getimagesize($content)) === FALSE)
                die("Image not found or not an image");

                $width = $img_info[0];
                $height = $img_info[1];
                if($width > 740){
                    switch ($img_info[2]) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF  : $src = imagecreatefromgif($img);  break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG : $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($img); break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG  : $src = imagecreatefrompng($img);  break;
                        default : die("Unknown filetype");
                    }
                    $img_info = pathinfo($link);
                    $new_name = 'small_'.$img_info['filename'];
                    $new_width = 740;
                    $ratio = $new_width/$width;
                    $new_height = $height*$ratio;
                    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor(740, $new_height);
                    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                    $dst = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../');
                    imagejpeg($tmp, $dst.$new_name.".jpg");
                }
```

The error come out is

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

In the line

> if (($img_info = getimagesize($content)) === FALSE)

The link is definitly right as it shows the image when i copy it to browser

Comment: try var_dump($content); before the error to be sure the variable is set

Comment: string(19683) "�PNG  IHDR�{f�3PLTE�ll���BPjAPgANeAMcCQkV`v[dy^f|Ybxry�fm�?J`x}�pv�{��ANhah}ho�u{�cj�yydl�lr�jq�B넄       and more after i type it

Comment: `getimagesize` expects a file name as first parameter, not image data. A valid HTTP(S) URL of an image should also work - but then you would be making two requests instead of one, which might not be that recommendable. If you want to avoid that, store the result of file_get_contents to a local file first, and then use that for getimagesize.

Comment: you can save $content data in a file and after call the getimagesize function

Comment: if you can update your question writing your solution. it can help future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that what cause the error is that getimagesize is suppose to use the link instead of content